# VB.net function returns nothing, yet throws an error during comparison?

Tags: vb.net

In our code base there is a function which should return either an object or nothing.

The exact code is this :

```
Return Nothing
```

The calling method looks something like this

```
myObj = theClass.function()

if myObj <> nothing then // fails
```

Am I missing something in C# I would use an if not null check, why would this fail in VB.net, and how can I check the return val from the func is not nothing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to compare references (and `Nothing`) you need to use `Is` and `IsNot`, not `=` and `<>`.

That is:

```
If myObj IsNot Nothing Then ' …
```